# How do not lost filter data on a table.filter() call in Primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

PF 5.0.2, Mojara 2.1.21

I have DataTable with filters and my own autocomplete box for DataTable filtering. If I want to update a DataTable I use "PF('table').filter()", because "normal" update doesn't function. The problem is that "PF('table').filter()" reinitialized "filteredValue"-Backing Bean property list with filterd values from client and ignores the value in my own autocomplete textbox

```
<p:dataTable filteredValue="#{bean.filtered}"
                      value="#{bean.values}"
                      widgetVar="table" > 
  <p:column filterBy="#{bean.number}">
       #{bean.number}
 </p:column>

... 
</p:dataTable>

<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.textFilter}" />

<p:commandButton value="OK" oncomplete="PF('table').filter();" update="" /> 
<!-- no update  :)  -->
```

So for example before OK was clicked

```
Before: 
bean.filtered= { 1}
bean.values = { 1, 2, 3}
```

and after OK was clicked it will be changed to

```
After:
bean.filtered= { 1, 2, 3 }
bean.values = { 1, 2, 3 }
```

And I want that it remains as before.

**EDIT**:
I've accepted the answer but there are concerns. It does make the job. But primefaces behaves crazy, because set-method doesn't do what PrimeFaces think it should do. So I used filterEvent on DataTable to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior because you are using `PF('table').filter()`. What you can do however is add a `Boolean` in your ManagedBean, and update it everytime your filtered list setter is called. This way you will have to do:

```
<p:commandButton value="OK" oncomplete="PF('table').filter();" update="" 
       actionListener="#{bean.negateFilter}"/>
```

In your managedBean:

```
...
private Boolean allowFilter;
...
public void negateFilter(){
  this.allowFilter = Boolean.FALSE;
}
...
public void setFiltered(List<Object> filtered){
  if (!allowFilter)
    this.filtered = filtered;
  allowFilter = Boolean.TRUE;
}
...
```

Then, if `allowFilter` is false, it means that you clicked the button for the autocomplete, and your filtered list will not be changed.

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer. I've tried your solution, it does make the job. But primefaces behaves crazy, because set-method doesn't do what PrimeFaces think it should do. So I used filterEvent on DataTable to achieve what I want.